# Is there a relationship between capacitor ripple current and the transformer secondary current output rating?

Tags: capacitor, transformer, ripple

As an example: I was looking at a 10000 μF, 50 V capacitor with a ripple current rating of around 5 A at 20-120 Hz.

My transformer secondary is rated for 24 VAC, 20 A.

Comment: Perhaps you can form a rule of thumb for reasonable values of secondary capacitance. My recommendation is that you simulate your worst use case.

Comment: @winny not sure what you mean. can you please explain to someone who doesn't work in the electronics/electrical industry on a daily basis? :D

Comment: Where is this capacitor going to be placed?  Right across the secondary windings?  Is there rectifier (half wave, full wave, bridge) in there someplace?

Comment: There is a relationship between how much capacitance you need for a given voltage and power, hence you could come up with a reasonable rule of thumb value for capacitor ripple current rating to output current. Please simulate it.

Comment: Upvoted because question is interesting, but OP should provide more information and a schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are simulations for a 24 VAC 4 A transformer having 260 mOhm secondary with 10,000 uF capacitor and 8 ohm load. I ran it at other values as well. Your transformer would have less internal resistance so output would be higher. K factor (leakage inductance) will also affect output.

[image: Simulation with K=1]

[image: Simulation with K=0.998]

Note: Values in first column are with 1000 uF.

(edit2) Adding a 30 mH inductor in series with the input seems to be equivalent to 0.998 coupling factor. And a 47 ohm + 100 nF snubber takes care of the oscillations.

As an answer to the OP's question, there does not seem to be a great deal of a relationship between ripple current and transformer secondary current rating. Ripple current seems to be about 70% more than output current, but adding a bit of leakage inductance makes the two currents about equal.